# Node.js running under IIS Express Keeps Crashing

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure, iis-express

I recently resinstalled Windows 7 on my machine and went back to downloading and installing the tools to help me continue developing node.js windows azure web applications.  I followed the instructions given on the node.js azure site:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

and using web installer 4.0 it says I have successfully installed these tools:

- Windows Azure Powershell
- Windows Azure SDK for Node.js - June 2012
- Windows Azure SDK for .Net (VS 2012 RC) - June 2012
- IIS Recommend Configuration

The problem I am experiencing is that when I run the site using powershell e.g:

start-azureemulator -launch

it goes ahead and runs IIS Express, and after several minutes IIS Express crashes with the following information:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   iisexpress.exe
Application Version:    8.0.8298.0
Application Timestamp:  4f620349
Fault Module Name:  iiscore.dll
Fault Module Version:   8.0.8298.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 4f63b65c
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00021767
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.28
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   f66d
Additional Information 2:   f66d807b515d6b2dc6f28f66db769a01
Additional Information 3:   7b2f
Additional Information 4:   7b2f6797d07ebc2c23f2b227e779722e
```

I am running 2 instances each time, and both of them crash one after the other.  Is anyone experiencing something similar and fix this issue ?  Is their an upgrade I need to do ?  I've run windows update but it says I've got all the latest updates etc.

Can I tell the powershell cmdlet to use IIS 7 instead of IIS Express?  I'm guessing its something to do with IIS Express on my machine.

I did some hunting around and found this person here who experienced a similar problem:

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/149

I've got a cron job running every 1 second, to check if any website totals need to be updated.  Could this be causing IIS Express to crash?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem will be resolved if you install and use iisnode for IIS7 64bit (instead of iisnode for iisexpress) from the link below as I could fix a similar issue in past:

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9784331

Comment: Hi avkash, I'm using a 32 bit machine though ?  Would IIS7 64bit run or install on a 32 bit machine ?

Comment: Yeah, no it doesn't work for me avkashchauhan.  It says I have the wrong processor installed etc. Any other suggestions?  I'm just going to reinstall windows, and start the whole process again, is there an earlier version of Windows Azure SDK for Node.js that does work, I know there is the June 2012 version but obviously that's buggy and hasn't been fully tested.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please install 32bit iisnode.exe on 32bit machine. I did not see any problem with my 64bit iisnode, and june 2012 SDK. you might need to remove some of other factors to resolve your problem.

Comment: can you just explain the scenario again, I'm just about to un-install and reinstall windows again, and want to know the order in which I should install things avkashchauhan. 1) Install windows 7 N (SP1) then 2) enable IIS to use full IIS on my machine, and 3) run the windows updates 4) and then what ?

Comment: you can download older version of node.js sdk for Windows Azure https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/tags

Comment: okay ill try v0.5.3-April2012 version, which is the immediate previous version to the v0.6.0-June2012.zip.  cheers